# Married filing jointly, whose name & SSN/TIN should go on 8938 for spouse's foreign account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, international

I am required to [file 8938](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8938.pdf.) as I am filing jointly with my wife. She has 2 foreign account in her home country. On 8938, the first items are:

> Name(s) shown on return.

should this be both our names like "John Doe & Jane Doe" or just her name "Jane Doe".

> TIN.

Should this be my SSN or Her SSN/TIN?

[The instructions state:](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/i8938--2020.pdf)

> Lines 1 and 2
> Enter your name(s) and TIN as shown
> on the annual return you are filing with
> Form 8938. If you are a specified
> individual (see Specified Individual,
> earlier), enter the first TIN shown on
> your income tax return. A TIN is a social
> security number (SSN) or individual
> taxpayer identification number (ITIN). In
> the case of a specified domestic entity
> (see Specified Domestic Entity, earlier),
> enter the entity’s employer identification
> number (EIN)

Comment: I am assuming both our names go in the name field and the "first tin/ssn" is possibly my tin goes into the TIN field.